# how to cancel a telegram chat join request using telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telethon, telegram-api

Some chats require sending a join request in order to join them.
I know that the request is sent automatically when using JoinChannelRequest(invite_url),
but now Im searching for a way to cancel this request using telethon.
I read that LeaveChannelRequest(chat_entity) function cancels the request, but I can't do it with private chats where I can't get their entities.

so to summarize my question is: how can I cancel a join request that was sent in telegram to a private chat using telethon

can anyone help me with that, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no method available in the API yet to cancel a join request.
You can try requesting for this feature on https://suggestions.telegram.org

Comment: [This image](https://t.me/c/1109500936/78413) can be considered one of the ways to understand how the Telegram API works.

Comment: thank you for answering, can you send an invite to the chat you just sent? (where the image is).

and do you know if there is any way I can set that JoinChannelRequest(invite_url) won't send a join request?

Comment: No. As far as I know, it depends on the Chat Settings of the chat which you try JoinChannel on. You can try with CheckChatInvite but i am not very sure of that.